# Why do I get a warning about printf() with %s taking type void * as parameter?

Tags: c, printf

I'm on programming project 4 from chapter 19 of *C programming, A Modern Approach*. My code works but I get this warning trying to pass a function returning a `void *` parameter to `printf` with conversion specifier `%s`.

> format `%s` expects argument of type `char *`, but argument 2 has type `void *  [-Wformat=]`

I can easily get rid of the warning by casting the return type of the function to `char *`,  like

```
printf("%s\n", (char *) function(param));
```

but I just want to know why this necessary since type `void *` is casted to another pointer type automatically.

Answer (score 5):

Compiler is very right to complain in this case.

As per your logic itself, the function returning `void *` could return a structure pointer casted to `void *`, but then, `%s` won't be able to print that, isn't it?

So, *if you know what you're doing*, you can *cast* the result, for this case.

Also, as others pointed out, maybe it's worthy to mention that, this warning has nothing to do with the standard specification, as in the standards, there is no restriction of the type of the arguments. (Borrowing Mr. **@WhozCraig**'s words) This warning is basically due to an additional layer of type-checking entirely performed by compiler on it's own, enabled by `-Wformat` flag in `gcc` .

Comment: There is plenty of standard-based fuel for the expectations of arguments when mated to specific format specifiers used with `printf`. But those are the expectations of the library routine, so if that wasn't how my answer was taken, I did something wrong. The language *itself* will (and should) happily take anything you give it so long as you fulfill the contract of the function declaration, and `printf` doesn't have much of one. Besides the first parameter, it will take anything (or even nothing). Enabling additional compiler checks like `-Wformat` is good for the soul.

Comment: @WhozCraig yes, sir, that is the same what I understood. Thanks. :-)

Comment: The standard is quite explicit that the OP's code results in **undefined behavior**.  See C11 7.21.6.1p9: "If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined. If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined."

Answer (score 4):

As far as the pure *language* is concerned (not the standard library and its expectations, the actual formal language) you can push anything you want on that argument list (including something utterly incoherent in relating to the requirements of a `%s` format specifier of some library routine). Of course, unless whatever you pushed ultimately is, in fact, the address of a nullchar terminated sequence of `char`, `printf` *itself* will trapes into undefined behavior at your behest.

The warning you're receiving is based on an additional layer of api-checking within the compiler, not some violation of the language itself. That api checking is matching format specs with types of presented arguments for frequently-used standard library apis such as `printf`, `scanf`, etc. Could the author of that warning-check been a little more forgiving and ignore `void*` arguments for specs expecting pointer-types?  Certainly, but the point of the check-feature would dwindle pretty rapidly were that the case. Consider this:

```
int a = 0;
void *b = &a;    
printf("%s\n", b);
```

If that api-check feature is going to be worth any salt at all it had *better* bark about that mismatched type, because as far as the language itself is concerned, there is *nothing* wrong with this code. And that has *nothing* to do with what evil I just requested it do. As far as the language is concerned, `printf` is simply this:

```
int printf(char *format ...);
```

And the call I setup certainly fulfills that (bad for me, and thankfully, the api-checks of my modern compiler will let me know soon enough there may be a problem).

Comment: NIcely explained sir, +1'd. Also, I've edited my asnwer a bit. can you please review once?

Comment: The standard treats the `void *b = &a; printf("%s\n", b);` as **undefined behavior**.  The language (as defined by the syntax, constraints, and the C abstract machine) is far from okay with it.  The syntax is fine and there are no constraint violations, but the C abstract machine *does not define its behavior.*  As far as C is concerned, this code is nonsense, but it's nonsensical in a way that the compiler cannot always catch.

Comment: @sfstewman: Would it have been legal if `a` had been a `struct` whose first member was a zero-terminated `char[SOME_SIZE]`?

Comment: @supercat Strictly speaking, it would not.  The representation of `void *` is not guaranteed to be the same as `char *` (although they are on x86, x86_64, and other common archs).  The standard specifies that they can be interconverted, but the variadic functions do not do this *conversion* automatically, and the `printf` statement would expect a ` char *` and not convert it.  So, strictly speaking, it would still be undefined behavior according to the standard.

Comment: @supercat a closer reading of the compatible types section indicates that I'm a bit off.  `void *` and `char *` are guaranteed to have compatible representations and alignments (6.2.5p28).  However, if `a` is a `struct { char str[SOME_SIZE]; ... };`, then `&a` is the pointer to the struct, which is not guaranteed to have a compatible representation or alignment with `void *`, and would require an explicit conversion.  Taking a direct pointer to the member `&a->str` would be okay.

Comment: @sfstewman: I wish that when ANSI added prototypes, they had provided a means by which a variadic argument could have specified an integer type, an unsigned type, a floating-point type, and/or a pointer type, and said that any signed integers, unsigned integers, floating-point values, or pointers would be coerced to their respective types.  For binary compatibility with older code it may have been necessary to have two `printf` methods both of which link to a common core (a vsprintf-style routine with an extra argument to specify whether the argument list has had forced type promotions)...

Comment: ...but that would have eliminated all questions of whether e.g. an `int32_t` requires a `%d` or `%ld` format specifier, and would have made an 80-bit `long double` a useful type (even though some people think it's an x87ism, many processors without an FPU can perform computations on 80-bit `long double` faster than on 64-bit `double`).  Most of the damage from failure to include such a feature has already been done, but such a feature could still ease compatibility problems during migration to 64-bit `int` math.

Comment: @sfstewman "The standard treats the `void *b = &a; printf("%s\n", b);` as undefined behavior" - you either missed the point of my answer or chose to ignore it. I never claimed the standard made no warrants regarding the behavior of `printf` with regards to a non-matching argument to a format specifier. My claim was (and still is) with regards to the *language* the invocation of a `printf` as I have shown *is legitimate*. The *behavior* of that `printf` invoke is certainly *not*, but that isn't because of a *language* violation. It is because of a violation in the protocol mandated by `printf`.

Comment: @sfstewman Iow, the standard library has its requirements, and the api-check performed by the compiler for format-spec apis is one tool to assist in those requirements, but the language itself will take quite-literally anything you throw at it once `...` is encountered in the argument specification, *and it has to; that's the way the language works*.

Answer (score 2):

A pointer is a variable which points to a single memory location.

The number of bytes pointed by the pointer depends on the type of the pointer. So if it is int* then it is interpreted as 4 bytes,if it is a char* it is interpreted as 1 byte.

A void* has no type. So the compiler cant dereference this pointer. So in order for the compiler to understand the memory to be dereferenced we need typecasting here.

Comment: Excuse meplease, but are you sure about `compiler cant dereference this pointer` part? isn;t is like that It would be implicitly converted to `char *`? IMHO, it's due to the additional check by the compiler, nothing from the standard.

Comment: @SouravGhosh "*... It would be implicitly converted to `char *`?*" No, dereferencing `void*` gives `void` (C11 Draft 6.5.3.2/4) which is useless. There are implementations which treat `void`-pointers like `char`-pointer in terms of applying the `[]` or `*` operators, but this are **extensions** to the C-Standard.

Answer (score 1):

The `printf` function is declared as something like this:

```
int printf(char *format ...);
```

Here `...` denotes any additional arguments the caller supplied (that is, your string you wanted to print). When `printf` examines these additional parameters, it uses some low-level code, which has no type safety.

This code *cannot determine* that the parameter has type `void*`, and cast it to `char*` automatically. Instead, if the binary representation of `void*` and `char*` is the same, the parameter can be extracted from the `...` part without regard to its actual type. If the representation is different, the low-level code will try to print an incorrect value (and probably crash).

Representation of `void*` and `char*` is the same for all platforms that I know of, so it's probably safe (if you trust me, that is - please don't!). However, if you compile with `gcc -Wall`, as some people recommend, all warnings are upgraded to errors, so you should do the casting, as the compiler indicates.